# Linq to Sql Query select last column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

I have table like that

```
Id Count  Date
1   56    04.10.2012
2   41    05.10.2012
3   56    06.10.2012
```

I have only single new record per one day with Count updated during the day

I need to select the latest record using Linq to Sql

```
var result = from q in repositoryManager.Repository.AsQueryable<Detail>()
             group q by q.Id
             into grp
             select grp.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

the query above does not working it is returning first row instead o last.
How to fix that?

Comment: Do you mean that it's returning the first *row*?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `group by` since you are not aggregating anything. Try this:

```
var result = repositoryManager.Repository.OrderByDescending(x => x.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

The reason your method didn't work is because you were ordering each group (and each group only had one record), not the groups themselves. You don't need groups in the first place when you don't need to aggregate data based on the column you are grouping by.

Comment: `OrderByDescending` not exposed in my repository, i need to deal with AsQueryable()